# Windows Phone 7 Pivot control for WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-phone-7

Is there an implementation of the [WP7 pivot control](https://web.archive.org/web/20150715170117/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/stephanc/archive/2010/05/09/windows-phone-7-pivot-control-sample.aspx) that can be used by a "normal" WPF project? I am especially looking for touch support and nice transition animations =).

Comment: did you try to include the windows mobile libraries in a wpf project and adding the control?

Comment: @Marcom: Net yet, no. I'll try this evening, but I highly doubt that this will work. You can't include even "normal" Silverlight libraries in WPF, and they're not even compiled for a phone. =)

Comment: It is not an answer to your question probably, but you might find
this article interesting.                           http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/gg309180.aspx

Comment: What did you end up deciding for the WPF control?  I am looking for a control myself for use in WPF

Comment: @Luke: I postponed the decision. Matt's answer would be the way to go now, but I kind of hope that somebody else will walk it for me =)

Comment: @Jens, have you found anything yet? I will take a look at the source later on and see if i can make it work with WPF or not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to dependency issues you cannot use the control from Micorsoft.Phone.Controls.dll.

However, before the official control was released a version was created and released under Ms-PL, so you could try recompiling this to run under WPF. The source can be found at http://phone.codeplex.com/releases/view/49437

Comment: That's probably a doable solution, but I'm afraid you'd have to rewrite some code to make it work for WPF. Those controls could be useful though.