# Is there a panorama control for WPF

Tags: wpf

Everybody, is there a panorama control for WPF? If not, how can I make one.

Comment: What in the world is a panorama control?

Comment: @Alain: I believe he refers to [WP7 Panorama control](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTA0rbSxWBU)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078228/windows-phone-7-pivot-control-for-wpf

Comment: why is this closed as not a real question??? just because the moderator doesn't know that that control is it doesn't mean it isn't something that people search about

Comment: Pivot control is different from Panorama/Hub, it uses Pages under a common scrollable header that switch as you navigate the header. In the panorama all "Pages" are subparts of a big scrollable area, placed side-by-side

Answer (score 1):

You can download the WP7 Panorama control source code from [here](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) and convert it to WPF from Silverlight.

Comment: so,how can i do it?can you give show me the methods?

Comment: No, you have to do it yourself. If it's been done, it isn't public domain.